# VBA Instant conversion of letters to Uppercase upon population of Excel Cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am looking for a macro that will *automatically* be activated upon event.

If someone inserts a text value or a value that has text on `cell A1` *once he presses* enter and the cell has been populated **if** there is somewhere a *lowercase* letter it will convert it to *uppercase*.

However the catch is that it must be automatically without having to fire-up the macro yourself.

Comment: Look up events and in particular the Change Event: _Occurs when cells on the worksheet are changed by the user or by an external link._  I think that is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
    End If      
End Sub
```

Tested only in worksheet code.

Comment: Try without .Value if it behaves strangely

Comment: well i put lowercase characters in `Cell A1` at Worksheet 1 but they are not automatically converted to uppercase. I've put this code in a separate module

Comment: your code seems right however once i enter a value in lowercase like bdf it is not converted to uppercase automatically upon pressing enter and populating the cell i don't know why...

Comment: changed the code, the address has the $s in it by default

Comment: i've put the code that you have posted in a separate module in `VBA`

Comment: Godbless it works i will mark your question as correct when timer allows. Sorry for the basicness of the questions but my skills in `VBA` are a little rusty...:P

Answer (score 4):

Enter the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A1 As Range
    Set A1 = Range("A1")
    If Not Intersect(Target, A1) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score -1):

I asked this on another thread, and was able to do this quite simply

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Column = 7 Then Target = UCase(Target)
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If you wanted to do it to all cells, and not just the last cell if it's in a particular column, you can remove the "If" through "then" segment